# Use different layout for different page in Orchard CMS

Tags: asp.net-mvc, orchardcms

I have two pages,Home page and Blog page. These pages are using the same layout page. How can i use another layout for another page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to that is in the Alternates documentation: http://docs.orchardproject.net/en/latest/Documentation/Alternates/#url-and-widget-alternates

You can see there how it's easy to create alternates for shapes based on the URL of the current item. For instance, if you have a page under the URL `/another-page`, just create a `layout-url-another-page.cshtml` template in your theme's Views folder.

Don't forget to enable the URL alternates feature.

Comment: Yes,it worked! thanks for your answer!One more thing,i need to change my layout or may be theme dynamically in every week,how can i do that? @Bertrand Le Roy

Comment: Can you please grant the answer, then? Thanks!

You might want to ask this new question separately, to make it easier for others to find it. You should be able to implement a change of theme based on any criterion, including time, by implementing `IThemeSelector`.